# Getting a stack overflow error in R using when making a heatmap from relatively small data?

Tags: r, stack-overflow, heatmap

I am using R to create a heatmap from a matrix with 4 columns (treatments) and a couple hundred rows. This is all I did:

```
d <- read.delim("myData.txt",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE , row.names = 1 )
d <- as.matrix(d)
heatmap(d)
```

...But as R starts to draw the heatmap, I get the following error:

```
Error in lapply(args, is.character) : node stack overflow
Error in dev.flush() : node stack overflow
Error in dev.flush() : node stack overflow
```

Even more troubling is this particular matrix is a 1/100 subset of my actual data just being used for testing purposes. I don't really understand the nature of a stack overflow error, and therefore don't know if it my computer's hardware limitations, software problem, etc. I've tried running the same thing on a large computing cluster with 500GB RAM to the save effect.

Here is my sessionInfo() from my desktop:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Please let me know what other info you might need and I'll promptly provide. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Without your data file, it is very hard to help you.

Comment: Do you get the same error with a smaller, fake data file that you could provide to us?

Comment: Perhaps provide the output from `dput( head( d ) )` so we can *see* what the data looks like

Comment: Perhaps the information at this [link](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=15215) will help?